# No response for Device token request on the simulator

Tags: ios, push-notification, apple-push-notifications, ios-simulator

I am newbie to iphone technology,right now i m working with an application where i need to implement push notification.

I followed the link :

http://mobiforge.com/developing/story/programming-apple-push-notification-services#comment-7850

Also,Used the following code :

```
 NSLog(@"Registering for push notifications...");
    [[UIApplication sharedApplication]
  registerForRemoteNotificationTypes:
 (UIRemoteNotificationTypeAlert |
  UIRemoteNotificationTypeBadge | 
  UIRemoteNotificationTypeSound)];

- (void)application:(UIApplication *)app didRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithDeviceToken:(NSData *)deviceToken 
{
    NSString *str = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Device Token=%@",deviceToken];
    NSLog(str);
}

- (void)application:(UIApplication *)app didFailToRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithError:(NSError *)err 
{ 
    NSString *str = [NSString stringWithFormat: @"Error: %@", err];
    NSLog(str);    
}

- (void)application:(UIApplication *)application didReceiveRemoteNotification:(NSDictionary *)userInfo 
{
    for (id key in userInfo) 
 {
        NSLog(@"key: %@, value: %@", key, [userInfo objectForKey:key]);
    }    
}
```

Thing is,when i run the program,i should get device token in the debugger window,as per the code,instead i am getting error like :

> " Error in registration. Error: Error
>   Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=3010
>   "remote notifications are not
>   supported in the simulator"
>   UserInfo=0x6e055a0
>   {NSLocalizedDescription=remote
>   notifications are not supported in the
>   simulator} "

How should i solve this problem?

Kindly help me out.

Thank you.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Because the simulator doesn't support it... In the example it displays the device identifier in the console. The console is displaying the feedback from the device. It isn't the console that is getting the information, but the device sending the information back. So, just because the console displays information on your Mac doesn't mean your Mac is capable of directly getting that information. Sometimes it must be sent by the device. Try running it on a device.

Comment: Ok..I was not knowing that..anyways thanks for the explanation.

Comment: I posted this after Madhup's answer, mostly because it seems like you have some confusion over what the debuggin console does.

Comment: ya,it was all making confusion.

Comment: Thanks for the answer @Beaker

Answer (score 4):

The error message is self explaining, you should try to debug the app on real device not on the simulator, as push notifications are not supported to be received on the simulators.

Comment: That is true,but if u check the link i have mentioned,u'll find that in the example shown,token number is fetched in the debugger itself. Also then what should be the way to fetch the same?

Comment: @Sarah Please debug on the device that is all. You can not test push notifications on simulator.